# Should Live View and Non-Live View in Dreamweaver Appear the Same?

Tags: html, css, view, dreamweaver

I've noticed recently that my site's live view and non-live view in Dreamweaver look very differently. **Could this spell problems for user accessibility/aesthetic consistency?**

Essentially, all of my pages are rendering in the ways that I would like them to, but could I lessen the chance of layout/formatting bugs by ensuring that the two views look similar, if not identical?

There is no Javascript on the page in question. It's merely HTML and CSS. Both are validated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how much Javascript you have plugged into your website. The more you have, the different it'll look.

Comment: In this case, there is none.

Comment: Are you using the same screen preview for both of them? A different size preview may really screw up if it wasn't designed for that size.